# Vue component design is not loaded in main view

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, vue-router

I'm making a SPA application using laravel and vue. When I want to show a vue component in my master file, the component loads but the designs are not showed. It only shows a plain text in the main component it not shows the card design like in the default component. Can someone know what is the problem? Here are some of my codes.

[image: My output]

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    { path: '/dashboard', component: require('./components/Dashboard.vue').default },
    { path: '/profile', component: require('./components/Profile.vue').default}
  ]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes // short for `routes: routes`
  })

Vue.component('dashboard', require('./components/Dashboard.vue').default);
Vue.component('profile', require('./components/Profile.vue').default);


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

layout/master.blade.php

```
//stylesheets

<!--Main Content--!>
<div id="app" class="wrapper">

<!--Sidebar--!>
<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
        <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
        <li class="active treeview">
            <router-link to="/dashboard"> <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>  <span>Dashboard</span> </router-link>
            <router-link to="/profile"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i>  <span>Profile</span> </router-link>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
</ul>

<!--Content Wrapper--!>

  <div class="content-wrapper">

      <router-view></router-view>

  </div>

</div>


//scripts
```

Comment: what's with the sortable error?

Comment: I dont know about that error sir. I dont mind it really. Hehe. Do you  have any idea about my problem sir? @JayLi